# Is it possible two external monitors to HP Pavilion x360 laptop?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavilion x360 laptop (14m-dh1003dx) with specifications [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06435410). Specifically, the external ports are:

- 1 USB 3.1 Gen 1 Type-C™ (Data Transfer Only, 5 Gb/s signaling rate)
- 2 USB 3.1 Gen 1 Type-A (Data Transfer Only)
- 1 AC smart pin
- 1 HDMI 1.4
- 1 headphone/microphone combo

Is there any way I can connect two external monitors to my laptop and have them run in extended mode?

Comment: Your Type-C ports are incompatible with a Type-C DP/HDMI Alt Mode, so what you want, isn’t possible with the hardware you have. Your device supports a single HdMI external display

Comment: With that hardware setup, the best you'd be able to do is duplicate the one external monitor on additional monitors via a [splitter](https://www.monoprice.com/category/adapters,-switches,-&-splitters/audio-video-distribution/audio-video-splitters?menuDisStr=audio%20video%20splitters&sort=&TotalProducts=22)

Comment: The specs state, “Data Transfer Only” for both USB C ports. Thus no video over USB C for that machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your USB-C port is hopeless in terms of video out.

If you wish to connect two external monitors, you can use :

- Monitor 1: HDMI direct cable,
- Monitor 2: A Displaylink Certified USB-A to HDMI adapter
  ([random example](https://www.amazon.com.au/CableCreation-Adapter-Windows-Compatible-2560x1440/dp/B013G4CJM8)).